# How can add Thumbnail image in Drupal 7 site?

Tags: 7, media

I have set an image style as a thumbnail, but it doesn't render as my thumbnail style.  Instead, it is showing the original size of image.  How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the content type and configure in the manage display fields. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` considering article is a content type.Replace 'article' with what every node type you have and change the image fields display options as shown in the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks dinesh ,but i have already set image style to thumbnail and its not working ,then i tried for medium and large image style same Problem ,But when i add it to my custom image style ,its working fine .what would be problem with default image styles?

Comment: You can edit the default styles admin/config/media/image-styles/edit/thumbnail and see for actual change. If not try to clear cache or see dblogs for any warnings.

Comment: Although this is not usually the case for image styles, you can also try to clear your website's cache.

Another thing that you can consider doing is checking the folder permissions and see if any images are stored within your `/sites/default/files/styles/`. There might be some configuration mishap.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh and Prof Elm ,I have set 755 permission to styles and i checked out actual  change of thumbnail image style,also cleared cache but still getting original image instead of thumbnail..i have install media module in my site .Is it making any conflict with image styles?

Answer (score 1):

change image format from 'mange display'.

- Navigate to the Content types page (Administer > Structure > Content types).
- In the table, locate the row that contains your content type and click the manage display link.
- Specify the "thumbnail" format.
- Click Save.